# how to include specific applicaction.properties in spring boot war

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, war, profile

I need to create different application properties for a spring boot project and include the proper one in the generated war. I'm able to generate a war, but no to include the proper file in it. I have different profiles created, and different application.properties following the pattern application-env.properties where env is (dev, cert...), all of then placed in src/main/resources but I'm not able to pick the proper one and include in the generated war, even including "-Dspring.profiles.active=cert" to define the profile active. The war is generated with all of them. Any idea?

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
            <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>cert</id>
        <properties>
         <build.profile.id>cert</build.profile.id>
            <spring.profiles.active>cert</spring.profiles.active>
            <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

[image]

Comment: WAR will contain all the property files. You cant restrict. Also -Dspring.profiles.active=cert is used when executing the jar/war, not during creating the jar/war

Comment: Are there aby way to just add the one for the active profile ?

Comment: What is the issue if you have all the property file in the war?

Comment: There is no issue, only I dont know if the server going to know what application.properties use?

Comment: ok, this is what you have to do. Create jar normally. This jar will contain all the property file.
Now while executing the jar you will be doing ```java -jar yourjar.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=cert``` .
Doing this it will pick application-cert.properties file.

Comment: If you don't mention anything while executing the jar like ```java -jar yourjar.jar``` then it will pick default properties file, which is application.properties

Comment: Doing that and adding logging.config=classpath:log4j2-{env}.xml to the application-{env}.properties I'm able to generate war/jar using the proper files